# How do I measure NAS latency?

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage

I have two Linux systems at work which have different NAS servers. Our developer tools run directly from them. The tools seem to run very slowly in one of the systems. (The tools read-write many files which too are mounted from the same NAS.)

How do I measure the data transfer rate the NAS storages have?

Comment: please note latency and transfer rate are different things

Comment: Many tools are available but are vendor specific.

Comment: Ohk... I am actually interested in transfer rate, but I guess latency is inversely proportional to transfer rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather difficult to measure the data rates using reall application data. You'd need to use a disk benchmarking tool like [fio](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442451-inspecting-disk-io-performance-with-fio/) ([bonnie++](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/139742) used to be a favourite, but I prefer fio as it's much more customizable).

Answer (score 0):

Usually NAS systems have some kind of metrics built in. At least, a simple and effective solution for overall activity could be to measure the NAS network traffic, for example by reading its SNMP counters (or the switch port ones).

If you are interested in a subset of the NAS traffic you could run something on the given station filtering traffic to/from NAS (eg. [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/))

Comment: I don't have physical access to the NAS or the switches.

Comment: SNMP does not require physical access